# My code is not returning anything even if my database has its value

Tags: php, mysqli

When I try to display `$time_4` and `$time_5`, they have no value, they do not display at all nor appear on my screen. I am querying from the right table and the parameters for the query I inputted on $time_1 is all correct and when I run it into my db manually, it gives proper result.

```
$time_1 = "SELECT * FROM ".ATD_TBL." WHERE nik = '$nik' AND Date = '$date'";
$time_2 = mysqli_query($conn,$time_1);
$time_3 = mysqli_fetch_array($time_2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$time_4 = $time_3['clockin'];
$time_5 = $time_3['date'];
```

Comment: Is your constant `ATD_TBL` defined properly?

Comment: What does `echo $time_1` show? I bet it doesn't contain the values you think it does.

Comment: Echo the query. Is the value correct?

Comment: Do a `echo '<pre>'; print_r($time_3); echo '</pre>';` and paste the output

Comment: put a error check on your $time_2.

Comment: you should have a look to your php error_log in order to analyse whats wrong, notice that before using a variable you'd better to  test if she exists

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Here's the echo in php

http://prnt.sc/bzmr2v

And here's the result

http://prnt.sc/bzmrun

It does return the correct value on $time_1, but the others are not being returned.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    <?php
$time_1 = "SELECT * FROM `ATD_TBL` WHERE `nik` = '".$nik."' AND `Date` = '".$date."' ";
    $time_2 = mysqli_query($conn,$time_1);
    $time_3 = mysqli_fetch_array($time_2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $time_4 = $time_3['clockin'];
    $time_5 = $time_3['date'];
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I used your code above and this is the result I have

http://prntscr.com/bzn460 & http://prntscr.com/bzn5em

Should I try changing the variables perhaps? My previous statements above this code use the same format and it works perfectly, just this certain code is not working.

Comment: @CyanHijirikawa Date is a keyword in mysql

Comment: thanks for the help. it seems like it still doesn't retrieve anything. it is the same result as the screenshot I have provided above. The ATD_TBL is a constant I defined and it is working properly since the rest of my code is working, just aside from that.

http://pastebin.com/umB64hu1 here's the entirety of the code, note the script call at the bottom also doesn't work properly even if i uncomment it

Comment: it has been working for my past queries without any problems though. I'm not sure what happened to that part of the code @mohammed

Comment: read this article it's useful 
[mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)
it's showing how you can use mysqli_error () function to know what type of fault you have